# Building multiple projects in MS visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

I have a MS Visual Studio 13 solution that has many (ca 20) projects inside.
Projects share some source code files.

I didn't figure out how to build all projects at once. When I select them and do `Build > Build selection`, or just `Build > Build solution`, visual studio throws such errors:

`Error  249 error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: 'x64\Release\blabla.obj': Permission denied   D:\xxx\yyy\src\blabla.cpp   1   1   Project001`

Probably because that particular file is compiled by several projects at the same time.
If I build all the projects one after another everything is good, but it is annoying work.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that many of my projects shared the same namespace.

After making the **RootNamespace** unique for all the projects everything works fine.

This is where to find it in *.vcxproj file

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{85936F95-D218-4D69-B8F2-684C2A86F850}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>THIS_MUST_BE_UNIQUE</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

VS has a way to specify the build order of projects in a solution (Right click the solution in the Solution Explorer) If Project A depends on Project B then you can specify that and then the projects will build in the order you expect.

Comment: And is there a way to simply say compile only one Project at time? Because there is no clear order of the projects. There might be cpp files that are included at each project.

Comment: You have bigger problems if you can't figure out the proper ordering of projects (i.e. you'll always get build errors.) Having the same CPP in multiple projects shouldn't be an issue, it would just get built twice. Make sure your intermediate folders don't overlap between projects as that might cause issues.

Comment: That's it. The problem was overlapping intermediate folders! Thanks a lot. (If you update your initial answer, I'll accept it as the final one)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether you want to build all projects at once or compile only one Project at time?

When you run a project, VS will automatically do any and all building necessary to run your startup project. It will also determine this order for you based on the dependency tree. You shouldn't need to edit this under most circumstances. VS lets you do so by editing the dependencies. Right click on your project and select Build Dependencies > Project Build Order to see the current build order and edit your dependencies, which will affect the build order.

For more details I suggest you could refer to the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-remove-project-dependencies?view=vs-2019

Comment: I'd need to compile **all projects at once (at one click)**, not necessarily simultaneously. My projects doesn't depend on each other. They just share some source files. I think the problem is that several projects are compiled in parallel and then the same source file is compiled by two projects at the same time.

Comment: I suggest you may try to use [/MP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/mp-build-with-multiple-processes?view=msvc-160).